# SQL xp_cmdshell not recognising R library package

Tags: r, sql-server, batch-file, xp-cmdshell, sql-agent

I cannot seem to get SQL xp_cmdshell to run an R script that includes loading a library.

Am using Windows 10, MSSQL v15, R4.1

What I am trying to do is run an R script that has several libraries that load. It is running fine in RStudio and via rscript.exe but I cannot run externally from SQL

(NOTE: I do not want to setup the R scripts with SQL RServices (sp_execute_external_script); the version of R scripts we are coding requires R v4.1 code/libraries and SQL only supports 3.5. So I just want to call rscript.exe from MSSQL procedure or Agent. We do this with things like calling ogr2ogr.exe from a BAT file)

1. so to test I made a very simple Script is the file *RforCmd.r* (note it does not use "janitor", simply a test to see if it will load):

> #### load libs
> library("janitor")
> ####  do some calc
> a <- 1
> b <- 2
> x <- a/b
> y <- a*b
> print(c(x, y))

2. my batch file is *myBatch.bat*

> REM use rscript.exe to run the R file
> D:
> cd D:\temp
> c:\R\R-4.1.0\bin\x64\rscript.exe d:\temp\RforCmd.r

3. in SQL I am executing:

`exec master..xp_cmdshell  'd:\temp\myBatch.bat'`

but that throws an error in the output :

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>D: d:\>cd d:\temp 
d:\temp>c:\R\R-4.1.0\bin\x64\rscript.exe d:\temp\RforCmd.r    
Error in library("janitor"): there is no package called 'janitor'       
Execution halted
```

I have got in my Windows System Environment Variable PATH the directories for R:

C:\R\R-4.1.0\bin\
C:\Users\luke\Documents\R\win-library\4.1\

The BAT that runs rscript.exe works fine from a Windows CMD window (e.g. 'janitor' package is installed on this machine):

```
D:\temp>d:\temp\myBatch.bat

D:\temp>d:
D:\temp>cd d:\temp
D:\temp>D:\_R\R-4.1.0\bin\x64\rscript.exe d:\temp\RforCmd.r
Attaching package: 'janitor'
The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
    chisq.test, fisher.test

[1] 0.5 2.0

D:\temp>
```

It also works fine from RStudio console:

> source("D:/temp/RforCmd.r", echo=TRUE)
> #### load libs
> library("janitor")
> #### do some calc
> a <- 1
> b <- 2
> x <- a/b
> y <- a*b
> print(c(x, y))
> [1] 0.5 2.0

What I have tried

1. if I try instead to use SQLAgent and use the job step Operating System (CmdExec) then I get the same error as `exec master..xp_cmdshell`
2. If in the RforCmd.r I rem out library("janitor") then the xp_cmdshell or SQLAgent works, it does the calc, but of course no library loaded, which we need it to
   (e.g. not a permission problem in SQL running the proc or SQLAgent)
3. if in the RforCmd.r I specify the lib path:

> library.path <- .libPaths()
> library("janitor", lib.loc = library.path)
> /#### do some calc
> a <- 1
> b <- 2
> x <- a/b
> y <- a*b
> print(c(x, y))

then xp_cmdshell or SQLAgent still throw an error:

```
Error in library("janitor") : there is no package called 'janitor'
```

(works fine in CMD window or RStudio console)

Comment: Side note: I would avoid `xp_cmdshell` and only use Agent

Comment: So is the janitor library installed in `C:\Users\luke\Documents\R\win-library\4.1`? That's in your user folder, SQL Server's not going to have access to it.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - correct (i thought v odd place for R to installl libs.... user specific option?). from R Console .libPaths() gives:   

     ` "C:/Users/luke/Documents/R/win-library/4.1" "C:/R/R-4.1.0/library" '      

the janitor folder is in 1st dir listed above and a bunch of others.   

I will try to set that directory so SQL has permissions to it.  Alternatively, should I re-install R? It got installed at C:\R\R-4.1.0

Comment: @Charlieface - thanks, I know the security drawback. I initially tried under Agent as that will be the final setup but when it threw errors I reverted to `xp_cmdshell' to check there (and is faster to run)

Comment: quite update - i *think* is fixed. I will post answer later ... long night .. essentially reinstall R and the path to the libs packags so SQL xp_cmdshell can find the lib